# Can not close the service when close the background

Tags: android

I write this code in the onDestroy() method.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
MessageService.this.stopSelf();
messageThread.isRunning = false;
System.exit(0);
super.onDestroy();
}
```

And close the service in other Activity.

```
stopService(new Intent(MainOptionActivity.this,MessageService.class));
```

I tried many code, it can not close the service when close the background. Could anyone give me some advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple code for service class

```
public class MyService extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "MSG onCreate SERVICE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "MSG onStartCommand SERVICE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "MSG STOP SERVICE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    super.onDestroy();
}

}
```

and here is the code for testing this service

```
 startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));

    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class));
        }
    }, 5000);

    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class));
        }
    }, 10000);
```

this is working just fine. Also add this code in manifest

```
<service android:name=".MyService" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `System.exit(0)` on Android, instead use `finish` (in Activity for example).

But there is no need to stop itself `onDestroy` method, it is actually gonna be stopped and destroyed (that's what `onDestroy` method is for).

You stop the execution of the method with `System.exit(0);` and therefore system never reaches  `super.onDestroy();` point and service is not destroyed.

Try just

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    messageThread.isRunning = false;
    super.onDestroy();
}
```